# Configure OpenCV with GPU support on VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, cuda

I have tried both VS2010 and VS2008. In the process of trying to configure OpenCV with GPU, I have successfully compiled CUDA codes and OpenCV samples codes seperately.
But when I include the OpenCV libraries in my CUDA environment it doesn't work. The latest problem is when I compile my sample code I get the following exception:

> First-chance exception at 0x7c812aeb in test.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0011fb18

My code is

```c
/*this is the sample code in opencv website*/

#include "iostream.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp"

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    try
    {

        cv::Mat src_host = cv::imread("file.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        cv::gpu::GpuMat dst, src;
        src.upload(src_host);

        cv::gpu::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        cv::Mat result_host = dst;
        cv::imshow("Result", result_host);
        cv::waitKey(27);
    }
    catch(const cv::Exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I changed `cv::Mat result_host = dst;` by `cv::Mat result_host(dst);` and it compiled for me and worked. But I think you have another problem. Did you compile OpenCV with Cuda ?

Answer (score 1):

DOn't look at the error box that pops up - look at the console window.  OpenCV has error messages that are slightly more descriptive.  Tell us what the console says.

I had a similar problem with this same code.  I fixed it by
copying opencv_core243d.dll from `E:\opencv\build\gpu\x64\vc10\lib` folder to the work directory with the .exe.
Don't know why that should matter but it did.

Using cuda 5.0
  VS2010 express
win 7 x64

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who might end up here by reference from a google search or similar check out this thread. It may help: [OpenCV 2.4.3rc and CUDA 4.2: "OpenCV Error: No GPU support"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228762/opencv-2-4-3rc-and-cuda-4-2-opencv-error-no-gpu-support)