# Installin Open CV 2.43 in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Pleas tell me how to install open cv 2.4.3 in visual studio 2010. i Googled it but in every solution i need to use cmake.
i don't know what does cmake do.

i need it for my project. pleas tell me what should i do.

Comment: Most of the time, you don't need Cmake to use OpenCV on windows. Download the precompiled binaries of OpenCV from sourceforge.

[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228762/opencv-2-4-3rc-and-cuda-4-2-opencv-error-no-gpu-support/13231205#13231205) may help.

Comment: ...what is the meaning of install, you just need to reference corrrect header file and libraries in visual studio..

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the exe file OpenCV-2.4.3.exe (263.7 MB) from here - http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.3/ . After running the .exe file it will generate .dll,include and lib files. Add the path to OpenCV runtime dll’s (Dynamic Linked Libraries) to your Environment Path variable and you are good to go.

Add the include and lib folder to your VC++ Settings. Also, don't forget to add the linker libraries.

If your still stuck, try how to install opencv - 2.4.2 from here - http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/ . Although this is for  2.4.2, it will give you proper insight into installing opencv and you can go thrugh the comments to know how to install Open CV 2.4.3

Answer (score 0):

The process consist of three steps:

1. download openCV;
2. create environment variable;
3. create property sheet in visual studio.

   It is better to install by looking at the video
   link: https://youtu.be/zg15fPJ42OQ