# Visual Studios 2010 the program can't start because opencv_core243.dll is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, dll

I am learning how to use OpenCV and as practice I ran a program (in Release mode, x64). I had 0 compiler errors but got a pop-up screen that said:

> "the program can't start because opencv_core243.dll is missing"

However, I made sure I declared the correct environment variables and specified the necessary libraries/directories. My problem was fixed when I copied the following .dll files into x64/Release:

- opencv_core243.dll
- opencv_highgui243.dll
- opencv_imgproc243.dll

My program compiles fine now and works. However, I would like to know why. It feels cheap to copy and paste these .dll files. Did I miss a step where these .dll files would be generated automatically?

Comment: It couldn't find the dlls. Copying them in to the release directory fixed that. Have a peek at this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 4):

The actual solution for this problem is to append the path of opencv bin directory to the System `PATH` environment variable.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13231205/1231073) describing the complete procedure to install OpenCV in Visual Studio 2010.

There is a disadvantage of this approach. The prebuilt OpenCV x86 and x64 binaries have same names. So by appending the path of OpenCV to the `PATH` variable, you can execute either the 32 bit version or the 64 bit version at a time. To run the other version, you have to change the `PATH` variable.

An alternative to this, (my personal favorite) also involves copying the dlls to output directory, but this is done automatically at the end of compilation. What I do, is to create new environment variables for x86 and x64 dll paths. I create the User Variables `CV_BIN32` and `CV_BIN64` containing the paths of x86 and x64 dlls respectively.

After creating the User Variables,  open your OpenCV project, go to `Project Properties` -> `Build Events` -> `Post-Build Event` -> `Command Line`.

Add the copy commands for the dlls you require at the runtime.

This one is for Win32 Release Configuration:

```
copy "$(CV_BIN32)\opencv_core243.dll" "$(OutDir)"
copy "$(CV_BIN32)\opencv_highgui243.dll" "$(OutDir)"
```

You can change them for all the 4 configurations, (Debug/Release),(Win32/x64)

Now when the project build procedure completes, the specified dlls will be copied to the output directory automatically, and the error will not be shown.