# System Error When Run OpenCv Code "The program can't start because opencv_core244.dll is missing"

Tags: c++, opencv

when i run my code this error occurred : 
[image: a busy cat]

and my code is :

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened()) return -1;

    Mat frame, edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
        Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
        imshow("edges", edges);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i check opencv bin and dll's but this dll exist

Comment: Look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228762/opencv-2-4-3rc-and-cuda-4-2-opencv-error-no-gpu-support/13231205#13231205

Comment: Have you added the directory that contains the DLLs to the PATH?

Comment: If you're in a hurry, copy opencvcore_244.dll where your code is. If you have time, find how to add a system path to a folder and place all dlls in there for every opencv project.

Comment: i add directories in configuration properties and copy dll beside exe file but still error occurred . i test opencv in python it work but in c++ i have problem

Answer (score 1):

Copy the relevant opencvcore_244.dll from your openCV installation to %systemroot%\system32 (or %systemroot%\sysWOW64 if the DLL or your program is 64 bit).