# opencv 2.4.4 no gpu support error

Tags: opencv, configuration, cuda

In the post [OpenCV 2.4.3rc and CUDA 4.2: "OpenCV Error: No GPU support"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228762/opencv-2-4-3rc-and-cuda-4-2-opencv-error-no-gpu-support) , it is said that C:\opencv\build\gpu\x86... libs must be added instead of C:\opencv\build\x86... ones. But there is no gpu folder for 2.4.4 realese. I added opencv_gpu244.lib lib file for release and opencv_gpu244d.lib for debug modes on vs 2010 conf. which are reside in C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib. But i get opencv error ( no gpu support ): the library is compiled without cuda support. By the way i!'m using cuda toolkit 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure described in the given answer, still applies to the current distribution of OpenCV. There is just 1 small difference. The pre-built distribution of OpenCV 2.4.4 does not contain GPU binaries. To add GPU support, you have to build the library yourself using CMake.

OpenCV 2.4.4 is optimized for Kepler architecture GPUs. In version 2.4.3, only the GPU binaries are approximately 1.4 GB. So you can guess, that adding the code for Compute capabilty 3.0 and 3.5 would make this even larger. So it is not feasible to ship these binaries, and that is why the **gpu** folder is not present in version 2.4.4 prebuilt distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile OpenCV libraries using CMake with CUDA support ( there is a checkbox ). Before releases include pre-compiled gpu files.