# OpenCV Error: No GPU Support : 2.4.10 and CUDA v7.5

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am getting this error:

OpenCV Error: No GPU support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in E
mptyFuncTable::mallocPitch, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\openc
v\modules\dynamicuda\include\opencv2/dynamicuda/dynamicuda.hpp, line 126

I have VS2013, CUDA v7.5, OpenCV 2.4.10.
I have Generated OpenCV WITH_CUDA = ON, and have set the path too. Please help me in fixing this error.

Comment: Did you compiled the OpenCV library with CUDA?

Comment: Yes I did compile. The GPU I'm using is NVIDIA GeForce 920 M.

Answer (score 0):

See if your video card is compatible with CUDA 7.5? Also try updating/installing OpenCV 3.0

Comment: The GPU I'm using is NVIDIA GeForce 920 M.

Comment: I followed [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228762/opencv-2-4-3rc-and-cuda-4-2-opencv-error-no-gpu-support)..
But I just checked that my OpenCV 2.4.10 build folder does not have a GPU folder. How do I link the library files of GPU?
How do I build binaries for CUDA?
Any help is appreciated. I have been trying hard to get it working.

Comment: I think from 2.4.4 if you want GPU you need to rebuild binaries with CUDA enabled. This [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/13490/cmake-opencv245-git-repository-24-branch-windows-7-x64-building-steps-and-problems-solved-zip-with-dlls-available/) will show you the steps.

Comment: Or otherwise if you use older version, say 2.4.2 or older you get gpu folder by default.

Comment: Will try the older version.
In the meanwhile, i wanted to know if CUDA is easier to work on a Linux Environment?

Comment: I have built the binaries using CMake, but the bin folder has nothing but the opencv ffmpeg dll. 
Does anybody know where can i find the built binaries for OpenCV2.4.10?
Please help.

Comment: Try this https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.9/opencv-2.4.9.exe/download

Comment: Thank you @Veera. Is there anyway I can contact you to clarify a few questions on this? Or do you know any place where I can get some more guidance?